# Reading ABS diagnostic codes on a Volvo 940

Tags: brakes, volvo, abs, dtc

I want to read any fault codes stored in my 1992 Volvo 940's ABS module. I've tried the procedure described in the popular [700/900 series FAQ](http://www.brickboard.com/FAQ/700-900/BrakesABS.htm#ABSDiagnosticCodeRetrieval) without success. That procedure involves plugging the car's OBD lead into a numbered port, pushing a button, and reading the code as a series of flashes of an LED in the engine compartment. The linked FAQ instructions have me plug the diagnostic lead into box A, position 3. (Positions 2 and 6 are for the fuel and ignition systems’ onboard diagnostic, the so-called OBD-1.) However, I could get no codes to appear — not even code 1-1-1 for "everything is fine."

The only other diagnostic lead position available is Box B, position 2. (Every other position is just a blank hole.) Plugging into B-2 yielded a code, but I have no information that confirms whether it's the ABS module or something else.

Does anyone know the procedure for reading the ABS diagnostic codes? Perhaps someone with a copy of the relevant factory service manual (green book)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a solution specific to your car, but you may want to swing by your local auto parts store. They often have code readers on hand that they will use to read your codes for free. No idea if they'd have one that can do ABS codes on an OBD-I Volvo, but...

Comment: Pretty unlikely (few even have the readers for ABS on OBD-II cars as it's not part of the "normal" OBD-II reader), but worth a stop by to ask them anyways.

Comment: ABS isn't part of the OBD spec, so a generic reader won't do any good. Only a counterfeit of the original Volvo device (or something that speaks the same protocol) will work.

Comment: Also remember, this is OBD-I, not OBD-II vehicle. I don't *believe* there is a CANBus associated with it (where all things talk together). A code reader isn't going to get the job done.