# How to diagnose ABS problem (ABS light on) on a 1992 Volvo 940 turbo diesel estate?

Tags: diesel, volvo, abs

The ABS light came on after car was not used for a few weeks and a new battery fitted. The ABS light is now on all the time. The garage can't find the diagnostic plug.

Any ideas on either of the issues?

Thanks

Comment: The light means there is a fault with the ABS system somewhere. It's worth checking the fuses and relays if people have been messing around with the electrical system (ie. the new battery) beyond that, it's going to be a case of checking the individual wheel sensors.

Comment: 1992 is OBD-I, which is pretty much proprietary/manufacturer specific diagnostics. Your best bet is a Haynes or similar manual for that model. Otherwise, what Sam Jones said.

Comment: Sam, your comment should be an answer. This is a question/answer site.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you should do is check for a blown fuse, it's very easy to blow a fuse when taking a battery out or installing a new battery.

There is an ABS sensor near each of your four wheels, if one has gone bad or is disconnected, that will cause your ABS light to stay on. It's a 1992, so the garage may have to forego using any diagnostic readers and test each ABS sensor, or worst case scenario replace all 4 if you want that ABS light to go away.

Answer (score 2):

The ABS diagnostic port is under the hood, in the same assembly as the OBD port. I have never been able to get information from it, however. [The best instructions I've been able to find](http://www.brickboard.com/FAQ/700-900/BrakesABS.htm#ABSDiagnosticCodeRetrieval) did not work when I tried them.

I asked a question about this previously, but so far it does not have an answer:

[Reading ABS diagnostic codes on a Volvo 940](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/601/reading-abs-diagnostic-codes-on-a-volvo-940)

Answer (score 1):

The diagnostic plug is under the hood. Set the wire for the port you need to check. Hold the button down for 2 sec. then let it go. The light gone blink. 1 - 1 - 1 if there is no fault. Otherwise it will blink if something is wrong. Check all the connections in the diagnostic plug.